# How to declare an array as a property of an object in an object constructor?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an array as a property to an object in its constructor, like so:

```
let object {
  entries = [],
}
```

But when I try to access the "entries" property, either inside a function of the object itself, or in an outside function, it isn't recognized as an array.

Comment: `{ key: value }` <= `:`

Comment: Also `let object = {}`

Comment: I'd recommend a structured tutorial on basic syntax when you come to *any* new language.

Comment: let object = { "entries": [ 
 {"name1": "value1"},
 {"name2": "value2"},
  ],
}

Comment: @RajkumarM thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Isn't this called an object `literal` or `definition` and not `constructor`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a syntax error in constructing the object, there shouldn't be any issue accessing an array in an object:

```js
let object = {
  entries: [],
  getEntries() {
      return this.entries;
  }
}
object.entries.push('it works');
console.log(object.entries)
console.log(object.getEntries())
```

Comment: Yes! It was a very basic syntax error in which I tried to declare the array with "=" instead of ":".

Thanks